# invokeall() wiht Future Versus CompletableFuture

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

As per [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll-java.util.Collection-) :

> `invokeAll()` : Executes the given tasks, returning a list of Futures holding their status and results when all complete. `Future.isDone()` is true for each element of the returned list. Note that a completed task could have terminated either normally or by throwing an exception. The results of this method are undefined if the given collection is modified while this operation is in progress.

[`CompletableFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) also implements Future with the following policies:

> - Since (unlike `FutureTask`) this class has no direct control over the computation that causes it to be completed, cancellation is treated as just another form of exceptional completion. Method cancel has the same effect as `completeExceptionally(new CancellationException())`. Method `isCompletedExceptionally()` can be used to determine if a `CompletableFuture` completed in any exceptional fashion.
> - In case of exceptional completion with a `CompletionException`, methods `get()` and `get(long, TimeUnit)` throw an `ExecutionException` with the same cause as held in the corresponding `CompletionException`. To simplify usage in most contexts, this class also defines methods `join()` and `getNow(T)` that instead throw the `CompletionException` directly in these cases.

What are the differences between

> - `invokeAll()` with `Future`
> - `CompletableFuture`

Since JDK 1.7 does not support `CompletableFuture`, can the same result will be achieved with `invokeAll()` with `Future`?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Corrected the question.

Comment: `CompletableFuture` simply provides the possibility to act on the result asynchronously. `Future` does not.

Comment: I have checked the question now. That question converts 1.7 code to 1.8 compatible code. I am looking for achieving 1.8 feature with 1.7 code as I cannot upgrade JDK to 1.8

Comment: Sorry, misread. The simple answer is: no. You'll need something similar to `CompletableFuture` for that added behavior. Guava provides `ListenableFuture`. The conversion is the same as in that previous post. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30159229/how-to-convert-java-futurev-to-guava-listenablefuturev).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can, if you write a bit of code:

1. Copy/implement (the needed/related parts from) the `CompletableFuture`. For an example check [this implementation on grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.java).
2. Extend an `ExecutorService` (that you already use), and extend the `protected` method [`newTaskFor()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/AbstractExecutorService.html#newTaskFor%28java.util.concurrent.Callable%29) responsible for instantiating `Future`s from a `Runnable` or a `Callable`, creating a `new CompletableFuture()` in it.